# Conditional Probability Given Zero Probability Events

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ and $Z$ are two continuous random variable and $Y$ discrete. I'm trying to prove $$P(X\leq x,Y=y|Z=z)=P(X\leq x|Y=y,Z=z)P(Y=y|Z=z)$$ Here's my attempt: $$P(X\leq x,Y=y|Z)=E(\mathbb{1}(X\leq x)\mathbb{1}(Y=y)|Z)\\=E[E\big(\mathbb{1}(X\leq x)\mathbb{1}(Y=y)|Y,Z\big)|Z]\\=E[\mathbb{1}(Y=y)E\big(\mathbb{1}(X\leq x)|Y,Z\big)|Z]$$ I guess if I can pull $E\big(\mathbb{1}(X\leq x)|Y,Z\big)$ out of the first expectation, then I'm done, but without, say $X$ and $Y$ are independent given $Z$, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your solution, it is not clear, why do you replace the random variable (the product of two indicators) with an expectation under such condition (in the second line). You should have $\Bbb{1}(X\leq x)\Bbb{1}(Y=y) = \Bbb{E}(\Bbb{1}(X\leq x)\Bbb{1}(Y=y)|X,Y)$, not $\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{1}(X\leq x)\Bbb{1}(Y=y)|Y, Z)$.

This problem does not require involving expectations, you can just use the definition of conditional probablity:

$$P(X\leq x|Y=y,Z=z)P(Y=y|Z=z) = \lim\limits_{\varepsilon \to 0+}\dfrac{P(X\leq x, Y=y,z-\varepsilon<Z<z+\varepsilon)}{P(Y=y,z-\varepsilon<Z<z+\varepsilon)} \cdot \lim\limits_{\varepsilon \to 0+}\dfrac{P(Y=y,z-\varepsilon<Z<z+\varepsilon)}{P(z-\varepsilon<Z<z+\varepsilon)} = \lim\limits_{\varepsilon \to 0+} \dfrac{P(X\leq x, Y=y,z-\varepsilon<Z<z+\varepsilon)}{P(z-\varepsilon<Z<z+\varepsilon)} = P(X\leq x, Y=y|Z=z)$$

Comment: Part of the problem is that $P(Z=z) = 0$. Thus you need a better definition of conditional probabilities than elementary Bayes' rule. This definition is often stated in terms of conditional expectation.

Comment: @Oliver AFAIK, the concept of conditional expectation is defined using the concept of conditional probability. The latter one is not defined when the condition has a 0 probability.

Comment: @Oliver If $Z$ is discrete random variable then $Z$ can never happen to be $z$ if $\Bbb{P}(Z=z) = 0$, so this condition wouldn't make sense. If $Z$ is continuous then we should consider density functions and replace corresponding probabilities with density functions.

Comment: @Ramil Thanks for your answer! The reason I replaced it with expectation is that since Z is continuous, I think the conditional distribution is defined on the sigma-algebra generated by Z, so I found it easier to me to translate into expectation. Bayesian rule seems not working because the denominator would be 0.

Comment: @Ecthelion Oh, I see. Could you please tell me the definition of conditional probability that you use in this case?

Comment: @Ecthelion I edited the answer accordingly, I define $P(A|Z=z_0) $ as $P(A|Z=z_0):= \lim\limits_{\varepsilon \to 0+} \dfrac{P(A, z_0 - \varepsilon < Z < z_0 + \varepsilon)}{P(z_0 - \varepsilon < Z < z_0 + \varepsilon)}$. But all the same, your statement follows from the defenition immediately after a bit of algebra.

Comment: @Ramil There are many different (equivalent) definitions for probabilities and conditional probabilities. Some of them use expectation, some of them don't.

Comment: @Oliver Could you please provide some references where I can read more about defining conditional probabilities through expectations (not vice versa)?